# Creating a ScriptableObject during playmode loses array information after exit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I made a little editor script that helps me create templates for a dungeon generator. But when I want to use the information saved in the ScriptableObject the array seems to throw a NullReferenceException.
This class creates a grid that is editable in the game view and then uses the next class to turn the information into a new ScriptableObject.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using RoomTypes;
using TileTypes;

public class CreateRoom : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject tile;
public TileType curTileType;
public RoomType type;
public Tile[,] grid;
public int width;
public int height;

public TileButton[,] tileButtons;
private GameObject tileParent;

public void Create()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            grid[x, y] = new Tile( tileButtons[x, y].tileType ) ;
        }
    }
    CreateSORoom.CreateRoom(type, grid, width, height);
}

public void CreateGrid()
{
    tileButtons = new TileButton[width, height];
    DeleteGrid();
    FindObjectOfType<CreateRoomCamera>().SetCamera(width, height);
    if (!tileParent) tileParent = new GameObject("TileParent");
    grid = new Tile[width, height];
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            GameObject newTile = Instantiate(tile, tileParent.transform);
            newTile.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new 
Vector3(0.5f + x, 0.5f + y);
            tileButtons[x, y] = newTile.GetComponent<TileButton>();
            tileButtons[x, y].xCoord = x;
            tileButtons[x, y].yCoord = y;
        }
    }
}
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(CreateRoom))]
public class CreateRoomEditor : Editor
{
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    CreateRoom createRoom = (CreateRoom)target;

    base.OnInspectorGUI();
    if (GUILayout.Button("Create Grid"))
    {
        createRoom.CreateGrid();
    }
    if (GUILayout.Button("Create Room"))
    {
        createRoom.Create();
    }
}
}
```

This is the class that creates the Object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;
using RoomTypes;
using TileTypes;

public static class CreateSORoom
{
public static void CreateRoom(RoomType type, Tile[,] grid, int width, int 
height)
{
    Room room = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Room>();

    string path = "Assets/LevelGeneration/RoomCreation/Rooms/";
    string assetName = "";
    if (type == RoomType.LeftRight) assetName = "LeftRight";
    else if (type == RoomType.LeftDown) assetName = "LeftDown";
    else if (type == RoomType.RightDown) assetName = "DownRight";
    else if (type == RoomType.LeftUp) assetName = "LeftUp";
    else if (type == RoomType.UpRight) assetName = "UpRight";
    else if (type == RoomType.Start) assetName = "Start";
    else if (type == RoomType.End) assetName = "End";
    else if (type == RoomType.Bonus) assetName = "Bonus";
    else if (type == RoomType.Empty) assetName = "Empty";
    path += assetName;
    if (Path.GetExtension(path) != "")
    {
        path = path.Replace(Path.GetFileName(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(Selection.activeObject)), "");
    }

    string assetPathAndName = AssetDatabase.GenerateUniqueAssetPath(path + "/" + assetName + width + "x" + height + ".asset");

    room.Init(type, width, height, grid);
    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(room, assetPathAndName);
    EditorUtility.SetDirty(room);
    AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
    AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    EditorUtility.FocusProjectWindow();
    Selection.activeObject = room;
}
```

}

```
public class Room : ScriptableObject
{
public RoomType type;
public int width;
public int height;
public Tile[,] grid;

public void Init(RoomType _type, int _width, int _height, Tile[,] _grid)
{
    type = _type;
    width = _width;
    height = _height;
    grid = new Tile[width, height];
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            grid[x, y] = _grid[x, y];
        }
    }
}
```

}

The creation works fine as long as I dont exit the play mode. After exiting and entering the playmode again the array is not available but the other informations like the width and height are still saved.

Comment: You will need to actually serialize the data. Just dumping it into the created scriptable object will not do that (unlike it does when editing those values in the inspector).

Answer (score 0):

Unity can't serialize 2D arrays. You need to use a 1D array `[width * height]` and access elements via `[x + y * width]`.

Comment: Hey.
I tried this but after stopping and starting the play mode the array still seems to be null.

Comment: If you're doing this to a CreateRoom MonoBehaviour in Play Mode, then it won't be saved because changes to the scene in Play Mode aren't saved.

Comment: so if I made an editor window and then created the room there it would save the array?
I made it in play mode to make it quick and dirty. would have to learn to make an extra editor window

Comment: An editor window is one way of doing it, but you already have a custom inspector with buttons to do stuff. Just use them in edit mode instead of play mode.